# BeautifulSoup import Failure when Running Robot Framework

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, robotframework

I'm running robot-framework on MacOS. I wrote a small beautifulsoup function in python that I can successfully directly invoke by itself (both inside and outside of a function) in a file we'll call BeautifulsoupFunction.py, listed below:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def get_image_urls(url):
    html = requests.get(url)
    source = BeautifulSoup(html.content,'html.parser')
    images = source.find(id='vi_main_img_fs_slider').find_all('img')
    image_urls = {}
    for img in images:
        image_urls.add(img['src'])
    return image_urls
```

The .robot file invoking it is the following:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           SeleniumLibrary    timeout=10
Library    ./helper-scripts/BeautifulsoupFunction.py

*** Variables ***
${BROWSER}    chrome
${SITE}    somerandomurl.com
${SLEEP}    3

*** Test Cases ***
mytest
    Open Browser    ${SITE}    ${BROWSER}
    ${PRODUCT_TITLE}=    Get Text    xpath=//h1[@id='itemTitle']
    log to console    "This is the product: ${PRODUCT_TITLE}"
    &{PRODUCT_IMAGES}=    get_image_urls    ${SITE}
```

When invoked via the .robot script, the python file fails to import beautifulsoup for some reason, even though it's installed via pip systemwide:

```
[ ERROR ] Error in file '/Users/myusername/dev/robot-scripts/test.robot' on line 5: Importing library '/Users/myusername/dev/robot-scripts/helper-scripts/ebay_img_links.py' failed: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bs4'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/myusername/dev/robot-scripts/helper-scripts/BeautifulsoupFunction.py", line 1, in <module>
    from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
PYTHONPATH:
  /usr/local/bin
  /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python39.zip
  /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9
  /usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload
  /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages
```

Does anyone have an idea for why this is occurring? I'm new to robot-framework and rusty with Python, so I'm hoping it's something rudimentary.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Your code works for me from Robot Framework. When you invoke outside of the framework, how do you do that? `python ...`, `python3 ...`, etc.

Comment: Just "python", really. On Mac out of the box I can run directly as "robot nameoffile.robot", whereas on Windows I need to run "python -m robot nameoffile.robot". Both are running python version 3.9.2, though oddly when I run on windows it's the "requests" module that fails, versus BeautifulSoup. Maybe I need an older version?

Comment: You do not have `robot` executable in your `PATH` on Windows, that is all. You could try with an older version, I have 3.7.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out my environment was messy on my mac, and that was causing problems: not versioning or imports. Upon wiping every trace of python from my system, reinstalling python3 via brew, and pulling back in all the dependencies, everything started working just fine.